# Sql Server Error: Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 6

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why would this query

```
SELECT * FROM Vendors

INSERT INTO Vendors 
    (Name, Description, StartDate, RatePerHour, Currency, Coverage, Website)
VALUES 
    ('Any','Any','12/6/2013','36.00','Any','Any','Any');
```

be causing this message failure

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'VendorClassificationID', table 'VendorScorecard.dbo.Vendors'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: What is your RDBMS, MySql or SQL Server?

Comment: VendorClassificationID is a column that is set to NOT NULL (possibly a foreign key reference).   When you don't specify a column name, SQL will still try to populate that column (with a NULL) during INSERT

Comment: SQL Server is what i am using

Comment: @ShawnSteward The table in the error message indicates that this is failing on VendorScoreCard table.

Comment: Actually, it is referring to the Vendors table, VendorScorecard is not a table name (in the error message)

Comment: @abhi no, please read closer

Comment: Alright lets start by reading the error message as it is amazingly self explanatory. You aren't submitting a value that you need to be setting. That particular column does not accept null value.

Comment: @Shawn how could this involve a foreign key?

Comment: @abhi In SQL Server, the fully qualified table name `VendorScoreCard.dbo.Vendors` refers to `Vendors` _table_ on the `dbo` _schema_ of the `VendorScoreCard` _database_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the TABLE Definition for the `Vendors` table. Most likely the COLUMN `VendorClassificationID` is a `NOT NULL` Column.

In other words, to fix this, you have to supply a `VendorClassificationID` in your `INSERT` Statement above.

Comment: @abhi no, it *does not* say anything about a table called `VendorScoreCard`. That is a three-part name; `VendorScoreCard` is the name of the database.

Comment: Who are you talking to? @AaronBertrand

Comment: abhi has since deleted their comment, complaining that you were talking about the wrong table.

Comment: oh ok. Thanks. I was wondering what all those @abhi comments were ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your INSERT statement is telling SQL.

Add a row to the Vendors table.

I only feel like populating a few of the columns (the one's I listed), so I expected you to populate other columns.   Use NULL or the column DEFAULT (if one exists) to populate them.

So SQL tries, finds a column (VendorClassificationID) that doesn't like NULL's, and politely tells you, "no can do...."

As Aaron pointed out, it is possible a trigger is involved as well

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at the error message.

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
>   **Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'VendorClassificationID', table 'VendorScorecard.dbo.Vendors'; column does not allow nulls**.

INSERT fails.

Wow the section I made **bold** is pretty telling. Apparently the column `VendorClassificationID` cannot be `NULL` so let's adjust the query.

```
SELECT * FROM Vendors
  INSERT INTO Vendors 
    (VendorClassificationID, Name, Description, StartDate, RatePerHour, Currency, Coverage, Website)
  VALUES 
     (1, 'Any', 'Any', '12/6/2013', '36.00', 'Any', 'Any', 'Any');
```

Done.

Of course the number 1 could be substituted by whatever value you want.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify `VendorClassificationID` which is a NOT NULL column in **Vendors**

Comment: VendorScoreCard is a database name, not a table name. The violation is happening on **this** table, not **another table** as your second bullet suggests.

Comment: (Not my down-vote by the way - I just think you should change **another table** to something else, or remove that bullet altogether.)